# How to lock a node from a certain role after changing state in workflow?

Tags: users, workflows

Workflow module lets you set who can change a certain state to what state. What modules can I use to be able to prevent a certain role from editing a node that is in a specific state?

Ex: if a node has been approved and is in Approved state, it should be final and can't be edited anymore by content authors.

Comment: Which Drupal version?  It matters in this case.

Comment: @MPD It's 7.x. I think I may have found a solution using the Workflow Access submodule in Workflow but it's not working as I expect. Still investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using Workflow Access submodule in Workflow.

Steps:

1. Enable Workflow Access submodule (assuming Workflow is already used like in OP)
2. Go admin/config/workflow/workflow/manage
3. Click the **access** link on the workflow that applies to the node type
4. Uncheck the roles that should not be able to edit in the given listed states

When I posted this info, I was using Workflow (and the submodules) version 2.3 and the author could still edit the node after performing the steps above. After updating to 2.4 today, it has worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For this you should have to implement hook_node_grants and hook_node_access_records. It look something like that -

```
 /**
  * Implement @hook_node_grants 
  */
 function MODULENAME_node_grants($account, $op) {

  $grants =array();
  $grants['Node_Edit_Permission_Content'][]=array($account->uid);
  $grants['Node_Edit_Permission_OtherRole'][]=array($account->uid);
 return $grants;
}

/**
 * Implement @hook_node_access_records
 */
function MODULENAME_node_access_records($node) {

  $grants = array();

  if ($node->type == 'node_type') { 
    $user_id_content = /* list of user id which you want to block */;

     // Revoke Permissions from these Users
    if (!empty($user_id_content ) {
      foreach ($user_id_content as $uid) {
        if (isset($uid)) {

          $grants[] = array(
            'realm' => 'Node_Edit_Permission_Content',
            'gid' => $uid,
            'grant_view' => 1,
            'grant_update' => 0,
            'grant_delete' => 0,
            'priority' => 0,
          );
        }
      }
    }

    $user_id_other_role = /* list of user id which you want to block */;

     // Grant Permissions from these Users
    if (!empty($user_id_other_role ) {
      foreach ($user_id_other_role as $uid) {
        if (isset($uid)) {

          $grants[] = array(
            'realm' => 'Node_Edit_Permission_OtherRole',
            'gid' => $uid,
            'grant_view' => 1,
            'grant_update' => 1,
            'grant_delete' => 0,
            'priority' => 0,
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return $grants;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, Rahul. But I found a way to do this using modules.